# Wrapper script that would record the execution time of another script with parameters

Tags: python, wrapper, os.system

I have a wrapper script `wrapper.py` that would time the full execution of `benchrun.py`.

Let's say I run the `benchrun.py` using this command:

`python benchrun.py --host {host} -f {testfile} -t {number of threads} -s {mongo shell path}`

What should I put in the wrapper script to run the `benchrun.py` script and get the execution time?

Comment: I would recommend you look into the `timeit` module for python. That is specially what it was designed to do. Run code and time how long it takes to run said code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, benchrun.py

```
import datetime

print ("sleeping now...")
time.sleep(10)
print ("done!")
```

wrapper:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

before = datetime.now()
os.system("python benchrun.py")
after = datetime.now()

print ("execution time: {0}".format(after - before))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the time before and after the execution and reduce between them so that you get the execution time;

**In the wrapper script:**

```
import time
```

**Before the execute:**

```
before= time.clock()
```

**After the execute:**

```
after = time.clock()
totaltime = after-before
```

The totaltime is the execute time of benchrun.py script.

Comment: If you're wanting precision timing you should not use datetime but instead use `time.clock`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using os.system to call the benchrun.py? If so, just set datetime.now() in the begining and after return, and calculate the delta. It should work.

Comment: yes I am using os.system.  I'm using time.time() for now. Can you please give example output of datetime.now()? It's difference from time.time

Answer (score 0):

```py
# timer.py
import time


def timer():
    def wrapper(f):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            tic = time.perf_counter()  # more precise than '.clock'
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            toc = time.perf_counter()
            method_name = f.__name__
            print('{}: {:.2f}sec'.format(method_name, toc - tic))
        return wrapped_f
    return wrapper
```

```py
# benchrun.py
from timer import timer


@timer
def benchrun():
    ...
```

Comment: By wrapper, I was assuming you wanted a decorator for whichever functions. Also, make sure to change the string formatting if you need more precision -- I'm wasting data by rounding to two decimal places, but you have the freedom to increase that.